# 2D interpolate list of many points

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, scipy, interpolation

This question has been asked before (see [[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34887016/2d-interpolation-over-list-of-points-python) and [[2]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57332773/how-to-do-2d-interpolation-in-a-grid-for-a-list-of-points)) but I have yet to find an answer that does not involve writing a time-consuming `for` loop. I have even tried structuring the problem a different way (see [[3]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66550017/interpolate-rows-simultaneously-in-python)) and was not able to achieve better results.

I would like to interpolate a 2D array at many different points. I have already tried using Scipy `interp2d`, but when you call the resulting function on n points, it returns an nxn matrix rather than just n values.

I need a solution that will be very fast, as it will be called hundreds of thousands of times, on tens of thousands of points each time.

**Edit:** my real data is too large to post but this is a toy example:

```
# set up interpolation function
d = [[0, 0, 1, 2, 3], [0, 1, 2.5, 3, 4]]
s = [[0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5], [0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6]]
l = [[9,8,7,6,5],[9,8,7,6,5]]
fxn = interp2d(d,s,l)

# interpolate at list of points
# (same as input points in this example, not always true though)
print(fxn([1,2,1],[0.6,0.5,0.6]))
```

The result is:

```
[[7.        7.        6.       ]
[8.        8.        7.2535014]
[8.        8.        7.2535014]]
```

Sure, if I take the left diagonal and re-sort according to the input values, I can get the expected answer `[8, 6, 8]` but I'd like to avoid this computational overhead if I can.

Comment: You should provide an example of your input and your expected output, so we can see why `interp2d` was the wrong answer.

Comment: I was able to get your desired result with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47087109/evaluate-the-output-from-scipy-2d-interpolation-along-a-curve).